# How to define a web service type in wso2 data service

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I created web service as mentioned below example.Anyway it doesn't mentioned the web service type whether its a Jason,axis or any other type.How to define the web service type when using wso2 data service ?

[Data Service tutorials](http://docs.wso2.org/display/DSS301/RDBMS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both WSDL files for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the "Content-Type" HTTP Header when sending a request to a data service endpoint to access it using SOAP, JSON etc. No need to specify the type when creating a service. DSS has inbuilt support for SOAP and JSON using Axis2. Refer the following blog post for more info. 
http://lafernando.com/2011/11/27/json-data-services-using-wso2-dss/

Answer (score 2):

Generally we use WSDL1.1 for testing, because there were some compatibility issues when using WSDL 2.0

Answer (score 1):

You can use either, but most recommended is 1.1, WSDL 2.0 was designed to solve the interoperability issues found in WSDL 1.0/1.1. But in most cases 
few vendors  support WSDL 2.0 today since it is still not completely interoperable. Though the
WSDL 2.0 is not advisable, it is better option when it comes to defining RESTful services. Because RESTful services can be described fairly with the structure supported by WSDL 2.0. Also refer [Should I use WSDL specification 1.1 or 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18959084/2764076)

Answer (score -1):

Actually there are two wsdl files. WSDL2.0 and WSDL1.1.Which one needs to be referred?