# Should I use WSDL specification 1.1 or 2.0?

Tags: wsdl

What are the criteria to decide whether to write WSDL's after the 1.1 or the 2.0 specification?

Should one use by default 1.1 or 2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to answer without any additional info.
While WSDL 1.1 is not an official standard, it is a de-facto standard, so many tools support it. WSDL 2.0 has little support from tools:

- Apache Woden - no recent development, problems with WSDL 2.0 generation.
- EasyWSDL - problems with parsing extensions, looks like version 3.0 is in development.
- tinyWSDL - some JAXB limitations and bugs keeps it in beta.

Note that WSDL 2.0 specification differs from WSDL2.xsd, so not all rules may be validated or reflected in XML Schema.

Nothing prevents you from using both. Woden and tinyWSDL have converters WSDL 1.1 -> 2.0. easyWSDL not sure (2.0 uses the same model for both 1.1/2.0, but could it be used for conversion?).

In any case you can convert 95% of your WSDL 1.1 into WSDL 2.0.

Cheers,

D.

Comment: Is that possible to backport from 2.0 to 1.1?